# Set and extract individual bytes of a number (lowByte() and highByte())

Tags: data-type, bytes

You can extract

> the low-order (rightmost) byte of a variable

or

> the high-order (leftmost) byte of a word

with the functions `lowByte()` and `highByte()` respectively (the quotes are from the Arduino Reference).

Does Arduino provide a way to extract *any* byte from a number with a similar function?

And does it provide a way to set *any* individual bytes of a number (which would be the counterparts to these functions, if they exist)?

Answer (score 5):

Any more sophisticated byte exchange can be done with binary operators.

### Extracting information

You'll need some constants like

```
MASK         SHIFT                                    
0xFF000000   24       (first byte, most significant)
0x00FF0000   16       (second byte)
0x0000FF00    8       (third byte)
0x000000FF    0       (last byte, least significant)
```

You would binary AND the original value with MASK

```
     0x12345678
AND  0x00FF0000
 =   0x00340000
```

and then bit shift it left, e.g.

```
   0x00340000
>> 16
 = 0x00000034
```

So from the original value 0x12345678 you have gotten 0x34.

### Setting information

The opposite direction is also possible with the same constants but opposite operators and in opposite order:

```
   0x00000034
<< 16
 = 0x00340000
```

and then

```
   0x12005678
OR 0x00340000
 = 0x12345678
```

Note that the OR operation only works reliably if the corresponding positions are 0x00. That's fine with a starting value of 0x00000000.

If you don't know that or you want to process an arbitrary number, you can introduce a step in between

```
    0x12??5678   (?? could be anything)
AND 0xFF00FFFF   (which is the inverse of 0x00FF0000 and can be expressed as ~0x00FF0000)
 =  0x12005678   (whatever ?? was, it'll be cleared out)
```

### Actual Code

Tested on Arduino Uno. The `long` data type is 32 bits or 4 bytes.

The code here may not be the most efficient. Advanced developers would likely not use `MASK` and `SHIFT` as arrays like this. This answer focuses more on the educational point.

```
long MASK[]  = {0xFF000000, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF};
byte SHIFT[] = {24        , 16        , 8         , 0};

// Extracts a byte from a larger data type
// value: larger data type to extract a byte from
// position: 0 based number, 0 = MSB, 3 = LSB
byte getByteAt(long value, byte position)
{
  long result = value & MASK[position];  // binary AND
  result = result >> SHIFT[position];    // Shift right, moving all bits
  byte resultAsByte = (byte) result;     // Convert to an actual byte
  return resultAsByte;  
}

// Sets a byte in a larger data type
// value: larger data type where to set the byte
// position: 0 based number, 0 = MSB, 3 = LSB
// newPartialValue: the byte to be inserted
long setByteAt(long value, byte position, byte newPartialValue)
{
  long result = value & ~MASK[position];                       // clear the affected byte so that it is 0x00
  long valueToSet = (long) newPartialValue << SHIFT[position]; // Shift left, moving all bits
  result = result | valueToSet;                                // binary OR
  return result;  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(getByteAt(0x12345678, 1));       // Prints 52, which is 0x34
  Serial.println(setByteAt(0x87654321, 1, 0xBB)); // Prints -2017770719 which is 0x87BB4321
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the value you `AND` the number with to clear the bits prior to `OR`-ing is the *inverse of the mask*. You can use `~MASK` to create it.

Comment: @Majenko: used and added in the example

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation, but I already knew about this possibility. So there is no inherent way to do this with built in functions?

Comment: You don't need to load MASK and SHIFT from an array!  shift = `position * 8 = position << 3` (convert a bit offset to a byte offset.  Also, mask *after* shifting so it's just `return (uint8_t)(value >> shift);`.  e.g. on Godbolt for AVR and ARM cortex-M0 get and set byte functions: https://godbolt.org/z/2uFXN5  Also included are versions that store/reload and use a byte index, avoiding shift loops on AVR which can only shift 1 byte at a time.  (Will post an answer if I get back to this.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: my primary concern was to explain it thoroughly and in an understandable, visible way. I am also participating in code golf, so yeah, it's definitely not the shortest form :-) In general I am not optimizing for speed as long as there is no speed requirement.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good explanation, but writing over-complicated code makes it harder for future readers *of the code*.  Also, I just noticed a flaw: your arrays are backwards!  Most people would consider "byte 0" of an integer to be the least-significant byte.  Your code gives the most significant, opposite of `value >> bitpos`.  (And opposite of memory order: AVR and ARM are little-endian).  I think the code in my Godbolt link is very readable, like `bitpos = position * 8`.

Comment: And as far as efficiency, sure small differences usually don't matter, but for a compile-time-constant position your GetByteAt version still compiles to ~50 AVR instructions instead of 1 because you forgot to make your arrays `const` and/or `static`.  So the compiler can't do constant-propagation through the array indexing.  (see the `test_...` callers: https://godbolt.org/z/chtKzJ)  That's a pretty significant difference in static code footprint for something you'd expect to be cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The header Arduino.h defines the macro `word(high_byte, low_byte)`. The
resulting value is an `uint16_t`.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question about the counterpart of `lowByte()` and `highByte()`. Are there any functions for the rest of my question though?

Comment: @LukasFun: I couldn't find any. But note that on the AVR-based Arduinos an `int` is only two bytes.

Comment: You should simply treat those definitions as samples, learn enough C/C++ to understand them, and extend them to whatever you need. If uint16_t is not what you need, why should exactly uint32_t be your solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternative methods, and they can both be easily used "in reverse" as well:

#### Unions

```
union byte_extract {
    uint32_t ival;
    struct {
        uint8_t byte_0; // least significant byte
        uint8_t byte_1;
        uint8_t byte_2;
        uint8_t byte_3; // most significant byte
    } bval;
};

... later ...

union byte_extract x;

x.ival = 65536 * 99; // change to whatever you want
Serial.println(x.bval.byte_2); //3rd byte
```

Unions are a way to define multiple possible ways to interpret a piece of memory, usually to save memory when you know something can't be 2 things at once. Strictly speaking it is not recommended to use them in this way but it works.

#### Pointer arithmetic

```
uint32_t *xaddr;
uint8_t *xbyteaddr;

uint32_t x = 65536 * 99; // change to whatever you want
xaddr = &x;
xbyteaddr = (uint8_t *) xaddr;

Serial.println(xbyteaddr[2]); //3rd byte
```

Memory addresses (on Arduino as well as on PCs) refer to the first byte of a variable.  If you have an (uint32_t *) you will read 4 bytes starting at that address. But if you have a (uint8_t *) or a (char *) you will only read 1 byte. You can shift this pointer-to-uint8_t forwards by as many bytes as you want.

Apologies if this doesn't quite work on Arduino, I have only tested it on PC.

Comment: This use of unions is well-defined by C99.  An *array* of `uint8_t bytes[4]` would be more readable and allow runtime indexing, though.  Your pointer-arithmetic version is only safe because `uint8_t` is going to be `unsigned char`, and `unsigned char*` is allowed to alias anything without violating strict-aliasing.  Note that both of these are endianness-dependent.